# How to solve provide parameterized type for this generic in SonarLint

Tags: java, spring, generics, sonarlint-intellij

I am trying to refactor my code using the IntelliJ idea extension called sonarLint.
In there, sonarLint suggests further modification like this picture below(I have marked the issue in red)

[SonarLint error alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmWD.png)

here is my code

```
 public class AbcController extends BaseController{   

    private final PermissionService permissionService;

    public PermissionController(PermissionService permissionService) {
        this.permissionService = permissionService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/groups")
    public ResponseEntity<List<GroupResponse>> getGroups( String accessToken) {
        List<GroupResponse> groupResponses = permissionService.getGroups(accessToken);       
        return getResponseEntity(groupResponses);
    }
}



public abstract class BaseController <T>{


    protected ResponseEntity<T> getResponseEntity(T t, HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        return new ResponseEntity<> (t, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    protected ResponseEntity<T> getResponseEntity(T t) {
        return new ResponseEntity<> (t, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

I tried to make modifications according to the sonarLint alert but it is not working.
Please help me with this problem.
Thank you all.

Comment: Where is the ResponseEntityTransformer in the code? I cannot find it

Comment: Specify the generic type, e.g.: `public class AbcController extends BaseController<ActualTypeGoesHere>`

Comment: thank you @AndrewS do you mean like this  public class AbcController extends BaseController<ResponseEntity>. but it's not supported for getGroups API return statement